# How to send binary data from client side to webmethod?

Tags: c#, jquery

In asp.net , i am trying to send the binary data of the fileupload control to the server-side web method.

Can someone suggest, if we can take the help of the jquery AJAX call to accomplish this task or other technique which can work in all browsers like IE, FF and chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This is nice done in [this plugin](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) which uses XHR for uploading multiple files with progress-bar in FF3.6+, Safari4+, Chrome and falls back to hidden iframe based upload in other browsers, providing good user experience everywhere.
2. Also you can achieve this using the [jQuery Form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/)
3. I found [this example](http://osman.it/aspnet/jquery-ajax-file-upload/) also really nice

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the ajax control toolkit to do things like this asynchronously.

http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, you use [jQuery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/). It can handle AJAX file uploads from the form. 
ASP.NET will have the file in regular Request.Files collection.